# How to implement the smart contract integration for data validation in hyperledger fabric sdk node

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts

I tried to implement the smart contract integration for data validation  (consensus with validating peers) in fabric sdk node. anyone help me to find the best example to assist

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you expand on what exactly have you tried?

Comment: @Artem Banger Actually i tried custom implementation of smart contracts in hyperledger fabric sdk, but i didn't get the best solution.  https://jimthematrix.github.io/Chain.html                            https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/tree/master